# recharts x-axis not showing 0 values

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js, recharts

I'm using recharts to show an area graph. I want to show values of concentration over time, including when there is 0 concentration.

Currently with the dataset going in I can't get the x-axis to show 0 values where there aren't any time value / concentration values i.e.,

```
const outputTest = {
    Dexamphetamine: [
      {
        substance: 'Dexamphetamine',
        dose: '20',
        time: 9,
        startdate: '2021-08-09T14:00:00.000Z',
        enddate: '2021-11-10T13:00:00.000Z',
        concentration: 0,
      },
      {
        substance: 'Dexamphetamine',
        dose: '20',
        time: 10,
        startdate: '2021-08-09T14:00:00.000Z',
        enddate: '2021-11-10T13:00:00.000Z',
        concentration: 3,
      },
      {
        substance: 'Dexamphetamine',
        dose: '20',
        time: 11,
        startdate: '2021-08-09T14:00:00.000Z',
        enddate: '2021-11-10T13:00:00.000Z',
        concentration: 4,
      },
      {
        substance: 'Dexamphetamine',
        dose: '20',
        time: 12,
        startdate: '2021-08-09T14:00:00.000Z',
        enddate: '2021-11-10T13:00:00.000Z',
        concentration: 3,
      },
      {
        substance: 'Dexamphetamine',
        dose: '20',
        time: 13,
        startdate: '2021-08-09T14:00:00.000Z',
        enddate: '2021-11-10T13:00:00.000Z',
        concentration: 0,
      },
      {
        substance: 'Dexamphetamine',
        dose: '20',
        time: 14,
        startdate: '2021-08-09T14:00:00.000Z',
        enddate: '2021-11-10T13:00:00.000Z',
        concentration: 5,
      },
      {
        substance: 'Dexamphetamine',
        dose: '20',
        time: 13,
        startdate: '2021-08-09T14:00:00.000Z',
        enddate: '2021-11-10T13:00:00.000Z',
        concentration: 0,
      },
      {
        substance: 'Dexamphetamine',
        dose: '20',
        time: 14,
        startdate: '2021-08-09T14:00:00.000Z',
        enddate: '2021-11-10T13:00:00.000Z',
        concentration: 3,
      },
      {
        substance: 'Dexamphetamine',
        dose: '20',
        time: 15,
        startdate: '2021-08-09T14:00:00.000Z',
        enddate: '2021-11-10T13:00:00.000Z',
        concentration: 4,
      },
      {
        substance: 'Dexamphetamine',
        dose: '20',
        time: 16,
        startdate: '2021-08-09T14:00:00.000Z',
        enddate: '2021-11-10T13:00:00.000Z',
        concentration: 3,
      },
      {
        substance: 'Dexamphetamine',
        dose: '20',
        time: 17,
        startdate: '2021-08-09T14:00:00.000Z',
        enddate: '2021-11-10T13:00:00.000Z',
        concentration: 0,
      },
      {
        substance: 'Dexamphetamine',
        dose: '20',
        time: 18,
        startdate: '2021-08-09T14:00:00.000Z',
        enddate: '2021-11-10T13:00:00.000Z',
        concentration: 5,
      },
      {
        substance: 'Dexamphetamine',
        dose: '20',
        time: 16,
        startdate: '2021-08-09T14:00:00.000Z',
        enddate: '2021-11-10T13:00:00.000Z',
        concentration: 0,
      },
      {
        substance: 'Dexamphetamine',
        dose: '20',
        time: 17,
        startdate: '2021-08-09T14:00:00.000Z',
        enddate: '2021-11-10T13:00:00.000Z',
        concentration: 3,
      },
      {
        substance: 'Dexamphetamine',
        dose: '20',
        time: 18,
        startdate: '2021-08-09T14:00:00.000Z',
        enddate: '2021-11-10T13:00:00.000Z',
        concentration: 4,
      },
      {
        substance: 'Dexamphetamine',
        dose: '20',
        time: 19,
        startdate: '2021-08-09T14:00:00.000Z',
        enddate: '2021-11-10T13:00:00.000Z',
        concentration: 3,
      },
      {
        substance: 'Dexamphetamine',
        dose: '20',
        time: 20,
        startdate: '2021-08-09T14:00:00.000Z',
        enddate: '2021-11-10T13:00:00.000Z',
        concentration: 0,
      },
      {
        substance: 'Dexamphetamine',
        dose: '20',
        time: 21,
        startdate: '2021-08-09T14:00:00.000Z',
        enddate: '2021-11-10T13:00:00.000Z',
        concentration: 5,
      },
    ],
  };
```

This is how the chart is set up currently

```
 <AreaChart
          width={500}
          height={100}
          data={substanceDetails[Substance]}
          syncId="time"
          margin={{
            top: 10,
            right: 30,
            left: 0,
            bottom: 0,
          }}
        >
          <CartesianGrid strokeDasharray="3 3" />
          <XAxis dataKey="time" ticks={[25]}  domain={[0, 24]}/>
          <YAxis />
          <Tooltip />
          <Legend />
          <Area
            type="monotone"
            dataKey="concentration"
            stroke="#82ca9d"
            fill="#82ca9d"
          />
        </AreaChart>
```

How would I have the X values display when there is no use of medication. Folling the documentation, https://recharts.org/en-US/api/XAxis, Domain should be able to be set, but it currently isn't - unsure what I've done wrong here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I see two problems with your approach.

1. In your `XAxis` definition you specify that only the tick with time number `25` is supposed to show. But your dataset does not contain a time value with `25`. Given that - no tick is rendered on your XAxis with the example dataset.
2. Your XAxis is a numeric axis with a specified (number) domain. Thus, you need to set your your Axis to type number, too.

In order to show the `XAxis` with ticks you could use:

```
<XAxis dataKey="time" type="number" domain={[0, 24]} />
```

See it working here: https://codesandbox.io/s/frosty-thompson-7czww3?file=/src/App.js